# Passing a member function as parameter of a member function

Tags: c++, class, function, pointers, member

I'm busy with making a leveleditor class in an engine but I'm stuck at passing a member function as parameter of another member function.

First I've made a typedef

```
typedef void (LevelEditor::*CallFunctionPtr)();
```

Then I have made a member function to check if the user clicks with his mouse on a hitregion. If so, another function needs to be called. So I've my first member function with 2 parameters

LevelEditor.h

```
void CheckClickCollision(HitRegion* region, CallFunctionPtr callFunctionPtr);
```

LevelEditor.cpp

```
void LevelEditor::CheckClickCollision( HitRegion* region, CallFunctionPtr callFunctionPtr)
{
    if(GAME_ENGINE->GetLButtonMouseState())
    {
        if(!m_bIsLeftPressed && region->HitTest(m_MousePosition))
            (this->*callFunction)();

        m_bIsLeftPressed = true;
    }
    else
        m_bIsLeftPressed = false;   
}
```

Then I've two stupid example member functions:

LevelEditor.h

```
void LevelUp();
void LevelDown();
```

LevelEditor.cpp

```
void LevelEditor::LevelUp()
{
    ++m_iCurrentLevel;
}

void LevelEditor::LevelDown()
{
    if(m_iCurrentLevel > 0)
        --m_iCurrentLevel;
    else
        return;
}
```

And now I want to call that function every tick to check if there is a hit. So in my tick function:

```
CheckClickCollision(m_LeftArrowRegionPtr, LevelDown);
CheckClickCollision(m_RightArrowRegionPtr, LevelUp);
```

And here I get the error on LevelDown and Levelup:

Error: argument of type void (LevelEditor::*)()" is incompatible with parameter of type "CallFunctionPtr *"

Dont know how to fix it. Tried different things, nothing worked

Comment: Ever considered `std::mem_fn`?

Comment: Dont know this yet but I will search it. Thnx ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CheckClickCollision(m_LeftArrowRegionPtr, &LevelEditor::LevelDown);
CheckClickCollision(m_RightArrowRegionPtr, &LevelEditor::LevelUp);
```

For your convenience, here's the working sample (the compiler is GCC 4.7):

```
#include <stdio.h>

class LevelEditor;

typedef void (LevelEditor::*CallFunctionPtr)();

class LevelEditor
{
public:
    LevelEditor() {}

    void CheckClickCollision(void* region, CallFunctionPtr callFunction)
    {
        (this->*callFunction)();
    }

    void LevelUp() { printf("up\n"); }
    void LevelDown() { printf("down\n"); }

    void Test()
    {
        CheckClickCollision(NULL, &LevelEditor::LevelDown);
        CheckClickCollision(NULL, &LevelEditor::LevelUp);
    }
};

int main()
{
    LevelEditor e;
    e.Test();

    return 0;
}
```

The other way to call this:

```
    void Test()
    {
        CallFunctionPtr p;
        p = &LevelEditor::LevelDown;
        CheckClickCollision(NULL, p);
        p = &LevelEditor::LevelUp;
        CheckClickCollision(NULL, p);
    }
```

Comment: Check your calling conventions also (I mean cdecl/stdcall stuff)

Comment: And please, give us the compiler type/version.

Comment: I'm just using the basic compiler of VS 2010

Comment: The sample I have provided works fine while using the VS2010 compiler.

Comment: No, does not work. Error on (this->*callFunction)();

callFunction: expression must have pointer - to - member type

Comment: It is just a living proof, not a screenshot from my workstation :) There's just something with the setup/settings of your compiler if you do get the executable with lambdas from DeadMG's answer and the code I posted does not "work" (a.k.a. "compiles")

Comment: Ow yea, I see. I will just mail my teacher with this problem. I'm sick of it

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `std::function` and `std::bind`, or lambdas if you have a supporting compiler.

```
void LevelEditor::CheckClickCollision( HitRegion* region, std::function<void()> callFunction)
{
    if(GAME_ENGINE->GetLButtonMouseState())
    {
        if(!m_bIsLeftPressed && region->HitTest(m_MousePosition))
            callFunction();

        m_bIsLeftPressed = true;
    }
    else
        m_bIsLeftPressed = false;   
}

void Test()
{
    // lambda
    CheckClickCollision(NULL, [this] { LevelDown(); });
    // bind
    CheckClickCollision(NULL, std::bind(&LevelEditor::LevelDown, this));
}
```

Comment: We are a little bit closer. The function works but only the first one I call. If I do LevelUp and than LevelDown, LevelUp works. If I do LevelDown and than LevelUp, LevelDown works.

Comment: This only means that there's some other problem with the code. E.g., your collision test (HitTest) actually fails and does not call anything. Look at the m_bIsLeftPressed. It is set to true and then... Of course, the second call won't work.

Comment: You understand me wrong. I can click 100 times on the hitregion for LevelUp and LevelDown. It will works 100 times but only in case of 1 of the two functions. Or it will work on LevelUp or on LevelDown. If the call for LevelUp is placed above LevelDown it is LevelUp that will work. If LevelDown is placed above LevelUp, only LevelDown will work. There is nothing wrong with my hitregions. 

I use m_bIsLeftPressed to have only one click. If the mouse button is down, GAME_ENGINE->GetLButtonMouseState() is always true so to get only one call for one click I use m_bIsLeftPressed. I've tested it.